# Why am I seeing a warning in Visual Studio that a .tt file cannot be found?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am really confused here...I have a project with a bunch of warnings about a parent .tt file not found for child files. However, both the parent file and the child files are in the same project.

[Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEMPf.png)

[Project Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPHnJ.png)

I've tried regenerating the .tt file from the .edmx.

I've made sure the linking is correct within the .csproj file.

Comment: Try delete obj and vs folder.

Comment: @MaxNaumov Thanks, I tried that just now and no change.